# Form with get method no longer posting to action url

Tags: html, forms

My form no longer posts to the action url.  Here is the html code:

```
<form method="get" action="/search-results/">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Why isn't the form posting?

Comment: Nothing appears to be syntactically incorrect with your code example. Maybe a browser or server issue?

Comment: Or you could have some javascript that is preventing the default form submission. Whatever is wrong, it is not in these four lines of HTML.

Comment: @markegli sometimes it's the obvious things on the page you don't think about after long hours of coding :)  Another script was interfering. If you want to add your comment as an answer, I will select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This HTML looks correct, so you could have some JavaScript that is preventing the default form submission.

Comment: Thanks again @markegli. Turns out it was a Javascript framework I'm using, SammyJS, that was taking over the form submissions on the entire site, in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Search">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
```

try this let me know give some code for problem you may past ...